# I want create new array from existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to create new array from existing array for chart.
I have big array, which have 200 objects,

```
let arr = forkJoin({
  countriesList: this.getQueryCountriesList(),
  nights: this.getQueryNights(),
  codes: this.getCodes()
}) 
.subscribe(({countriesList, nights, codes}) => {
  this.resulti = countriesList.map((obj:any) => ({
       ...obj,
       ...nights.find((o:any) => o.countryId === obj.countryId),
       ...codes.find((o:any) => o.countryId === obj.countryId)
  }));
  console.log("bbbb",this.resulti)
  return this.resulti
});
```

it console logs following array:

```
0:
ageGroup: 1
countryId: 6200
countryName: "Turkey"
countryNameGe: "თურქეთი"
gender: 1
id: "TR"
monthNo: 2
nights: 826728
tourType: 2
value: 326494
yearNo: 2021
[[Prototype]]: Object

1:
ageGroup: 1
countryId: 6162
countryName: "Russian Federation (the)"
countryNameGe: "რუსეთის ფედერაცია"
gender: 1
id: "RU"
monthNo: 7
nights: 1464507
tourType: 1
value: 212979
yearNo: 2021
[[Prototype]]: Object

2: {yearNo: 2021, monthNo: 8, countryId: 5974, countryNameGe: 'სომხეთი', tourType: 1, …}
3: {yearNo: 2021, monthNo: 1, countryId: 1, countryNameGe: 'საქართველო', tourType: 1, …}
etc
```

from this array I want to create new array, so I tried it with the following code

```
function createShortArray(arr: any)
{
    let shortArray:any=[];

    for(let item of arr)
    {
        shortArray.push({id:item.id,countryName:item.countryName,value:item.value,year:item.yearNo})
    }

    console.log("1234567890",shortArray)
    return shortArray;
}
createShortArray(this.resulti)
```

but it logs empty array.
can u help me?

Comment: Do you actually have an array? Or do you have an object? Please share your efforts so far as a [mcve]

Comment: @evolutionxbox I added some things. I have array

Comment: Please make the sample data more accurate.

Comment: This appears to be rxjs but beyond that this is un-answerable. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: why not only return the wanted data from the request of data base?

Comment: I tried to edit my question

Answer (score 0):

```
const sampleList = [
  {
    ageGroup: 1,
    countryId: 5992,
    countryName: 'France',
    gender: 1,
    id: 'FR',
    monthNo: 7,
    nights: 415055,
    tourType: 1,
    value: 53698,
    yearNo: 2021,
  },
];

const filteredList = sampleList.map(({ id, countryName, value, yearNo }) => ({
  id,
  countryName,
  value,
  year: yearNo,
}));
```

try this

Answer (score -1):

Just create another short array from existing array. Use the following function

```
myarr = [
 {
    ageGroup: 1,
    countryId: 5992,
    countryName: "France",
    gender: 1,
    id: "FR",
    monthNo: 7,
    nights: 415055,
    tourType: 1,
    value: 53698,
    yearNo: 2021,
},
{
    ageGroup: 1,
    countryId: 5992,
    countryName: "France",
    gender: 1,
    id: "FR",
    monthNo: 7,
    nights: 415055,
    tourType: 1,
    value: 53698,
    yearNo: 2021,
    }   
];


function createShortArray(arr)
{
    let shortArray=[];

    for(let item of arr)
    {
        shortArray.push({id:item.id,countryName:item.countryName,value:item.value,year:item.yearNo})
    }

    return shortArray;
}

console.log(createShortArray(myarr))
```

Comment: It returns empty array

Comment: I think you are passing the input array wrong. I have updated my code for clarity

Comment: thanks, when I log this.resulti it logs empty array and when I pass arr, it tells "arr" is not iterable